# Rxjs Observable sends undefined - how to avoid it

Tags: rest, typescript, asynchronous, request, rxjs

I have a GET request in Observable. I want to send it's result to Observer. Unfortunately it sends undefined value, because it communicate to observer even before GET execution finishes - and that's the problem.

```
 observer:Observer<any> = {
  next: objectFromObservable => { SomeActionWith() }
}


let outputToObserver;
  this.http.get(myUrl).map((programs)=>{
          const mapped = programs.json() as Program[];
      outputToObserver=mapped //here we always have desired object
          return mapped;
      })
      .subscribe(
        (res)=>{
          return res; //here we always have desired object
        }
      )
    //Here outputToObserver is undefined, so above lines are executed before mapping
      let observable:Observable<any> = Observable.create(function (obserwator) {
      observer.next(outputToObserver)
```

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what exactly you want to achieve with this code. If you can specify your requirements I can help in solving that.

Comment: Thanks, edited as good as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
getDataFromMyUrl() {
  return this.http.get(myUrl).map((programs)=>{
          const mapped = programs.json() as Program[];
          return mapped;
      })
}
```

From the consumption side you can do something like this

```
var getData = getDataFromMyUrl()
                .subscribe(res => {
                     // Process the data here....
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fire it as a side effect with do, the code can be more readable and linear in this case.

```
let outputStream=new Subject()

this.http.get(myUrl).map((programs)=>programs.json())
.do(value=>outputStream.next(value))
.subscribe()

outputStream.subscribe()
```